# Golang map put if absent?

Tags: go

I have a map of the format:

`map[string]map[string]int`

In this main map, I want to do something like `putIfAbsent("key", new HashMap<>()` as we have in Java. What is a clean and shorthand way to do it in Go?

Comment: The Go language in general does not aim for being super-concise. If Go had generics, you could write this as a generic once, and then invoke it concisely; but Go doesn't (yet), so you need a handful of lines, as in Burak Serdar's answer, which you must type in yourself, or use a code generator to produce.

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
var val map[string]int
val, exists := m[key]
if !exists {
    val = make(map[string]int)
    m[key] = val
}
```

If you don't need the `val` in the code coming below this:

```
if _,exists := m[key]; !exists {
    m[key]=make(map[string]int)
}
```

Comment: This is about twice as long as it needs to be - I assume that's just to make it more clear, but might be helpful to show also how it would more typically look in real-world code.

Comment: The point was to make `val` avilable to the code below once everything is said and done. I'll add the short version

Answer (score 2):

If you don't intend to use the value right away, here you go...

```golang
m := make(map[string]map[string]int)

if _, ok := m["unknown"]; !ok {
    m["unknown"] = make(map[string]int)
}
```

**Below is a suggestion for improvement:**
To keep things clean and easy to understand, you can define your own types. For example, if your data is a mapping of "cities **to** persons **to** age", I would do it like this:

```golang
type Person map[string]int
type City map[string]Person

m := make(City)

if _, ok := m["Dhaka"]; !ok {
    m["Dhaka"] = make(Person)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func main() {
    var testMap map[int]interface{}
    testMap = make(map[int]interface{})

    var addMap map[int]string
    addMap = make(map[int]string)
    addMap[1] = "999"
    addMap[2] = "888"

    Add(testMap, 111, addMap)

    for key, val := range testMap {
        fmt.Println(key)
        for key2, val2 := range val.(map[int]string) {
            fmt.Println(key2, val2)
        }
    }
}
```

```
func Add(_testMap map[int]interface{}, _key int, _val map[int]string) {
    _, exist := _testMap[_key] // _ -> value
    if exist == false {
        //addmap
        _testMap[_key] = _val
    } else {
        //whatever wanna to do
    }
}
```